# Change features from ggplot object without the code that created it

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I am trying to learn more about how ggplot objects work. I am trying to accomplish the goal of changing a ggplot object without having the initial code for it. So in this example I use `sjPlot` which outputs a model object `model_obj`. By not relying on the initial code used to make the plot, I'd like to be able to change 3 things about the plot. I'd like to be able to

1. Change the legend title from "Dependent Variables" to "Outcomes" (I don't really care what it's called it's just a test)
2. Re-order the coefficients on the y axis
3. Change the x axis bounds

I know the `plot_models` function allows for some of this already, but I'm trying to understand more about how ggplot works.
One idea I found online were people who use this `ggplot_build` function to extract some features from the plot object then change it and then revert it back into a plot with `ggplot_gtable`. However, I don't understand what parts of the output would correspond to the 3 things above.

I'm also interested in options that add on new features to the ggplot object with the `+` sign like this

```
model_obj + ggtitle("New title")
```

but I'm not sure this will always be helpful in cases where the initial code of the model object isn't known.

Here is my code

```
require(sjPlot)
data(mtcars)

# fit models
fit1 <- glm(vs ~ mpg + disp + drat,family="binomial", data=mtcars)
fit2 <- glm(am ~ mpg + disp + drat,family="binomial", data=mtcars)

# plot multiple models
model_obj<-plot_models(fit1, fit2)
model_obj

#extract features of ggplot object (One possible solution) 
q <- ggplot_build(model_obj)
q

###do something to the new q object that changes it


#get the ggplot back 
q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
plot(q)
```

Update:

A useful solution was proposed for the above example.

```
model_obj + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("disp", "drat", "mpg") ) + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", limits = c(.001, 10000) ) + labs(color = "Outcomes")
```

However, I found one case where this does not work as well. Take this example,

```
library(sjPlot)
library(titanic)
titanic_train$Sex_num<-ifelse(titanic_train$Sex=="male", 0, 1)
fit1 <- glm(Survived ~ Embarked + Fare,family="binomial", data=titanic_train)
fit2 <- glm(Sex_num ~ Embarked + Fare,family="binomial", data=titanic_train)
model_obj<-plot_models(fit1, fit2)
model_obj + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Embarked", "Fare") ) + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", limits = c(.001, 10000) ) + labs(color = "Outcomes")
```

In this case there appears to be a glitch where the estimates are no longer plotted. I'm guessing this has to do with the reordering part for estimates of single variables with reference categories.

Comment: So what exactly is the desire output here. What specifically do you mean when you want to "Re-order the coefficients on the y axis" for this example. The three things you mention seem like they could be solved with just `+labs()` + `+scale_y_discrete()` and `+scale_x_continuous()`

Comment: To add to the last comment, does something like `model_obj + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("disp", "drat", "mpg") ) + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", limits = c(.001, 10000) ) + labs(color = "Outcomes")` move you towards your desired output?  Note that two additional complications are that `plot_models()` must do a `coord_flip()` somewhere along the way so the observed y axis is actually x and vice versa and that the continuous axis is on the log10 scale do to the results being odds (I learned this last bit by looking at the code from `plot_models()`).

Comment: @aosmith this actually works well in this situation! However, it does not seem to work in the presence of reference categories take this example

`library(sjPlot)
library(titanic)
titanic_train$Sex_num<-ifelse(titanic_train$Sex=="male", 0, 1)
fit1 <- glm(Survived ~ Embarked + Fare,family="binomial", data=titanic_train)
fit2 <- glm(Sex_num ~ Embarked + Fare,family="binomial", data=titanic_train)
model_obj<-plot_models(fit1, fit2)
model_obj + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Embarked", "Fare") ) + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", limits = c(.001, 10000) ) + labs(color = "Outcomes")`

Comment: In the example above your estimates are no longer plotted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, it's probably easiest to work backwards.

When a ggplot is drawn onto the plotting window, what is actually being drawn is a collection of graphical objects or "grobs", which are simple geometric shapes (points, lines, polygons and text) as defined and rendered by the `grid` package. In a sense, ggplot completely sub-contracts out the actual rendering of its plots to `grid`. Instead, it is ggplot's job to work out exactly which grobs are needed where. You can therefore think of the end product of ggplot as being a collection of grobs. This collection is the gtable that you get when you call `ggplot_gtable` on a `"ggplot_built"` object.

Once the collection of grobs has actually been constructed, it is possible to alter it in place, but it is relatively difficult to do, because you are working with a deeply nested list of interdependent geometric objects. It always feels a bit "hacky" doing this. If you can, it is better to try to get the plot right before this stage.

In order to create the gtable, ggplot needs a complete blueprint for how this collection of grobs is to be constructed. This final blueprint is what a `"ggplot_built"` object is. However, at this stage, there are again many interdependent structures to consider : it is a complex ggproto object with nested data, attributes and functions, and is easy to break. Changing a `ggplot_built` object is therefore also difficult.

For the most part, we want to change the *specification* of the plot before the blueprint is built. The specification is what an actual "ggplot" object is. If we make a really simple ggplot object and store it as a variable, nothing gets drawn to our plotting window, and no `ggplot_built` or `gtable` object gets built. The ggplot is still at the specification stage and can be changed easily

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Only once we implicitly or explicitly call plot on the object does the final `specification -> blueprint -> grobs -> drawing` happen.

In your case, `model_obj` is actually a ggplot object, so you can change its parameters fairly easily. For example, if I wanted to change it to polar co-ordinates, I could either just do `model_obj + coord_polar()` (and get a warning that I was trying to apply two `coords`), or directly overwrite the coords. I'll stick to just adding them here.

```r
model_obj$coordinates + coord_polar()
model_obj
```

[image]

Similarly, if I want to change the legend for the color scale, I can add or replace the scale object. From now on, I'll overwrite so the changes are sustained.

```
model_obj$scales$scales[[3]] <- scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), name = "Outcome")
model_obj
```

[image]

Now, to reorder the y axis (which is actually the x axis since the sjplot object has flipped co-ordinates, I can do:

```
model_obj$scales$scales[[1]] <- scale_x_discrete(limits = c("mpg", "disp", "drat"))
model_obj
```

[image]

And finally, we change the x axis limits like this:

```r
model_obj$scales$scales[[2]] <- scale_y_log10(limits = c(0.0001, 100))
model_obj
```

[image]

Comment: wow thats awesome! Do you also have any idea whats going on with the second example I included where the `scale_x_discrete()` function causes the plot to stop drawing the estimates? Is that indeed caused by the reference categories? Is this a ggplot or sjplot glitch?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the second situation. I'm going to guess this NOT a `ggplot` glitch and actually an `sjplot` feature.

The reason things are not plotted is because you need to utilize the exact labels for the variables that show up on the plot themselves. So you can't do

```
model_obj + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Embarked", "Fare") )
```

because only `Fare` fits with one of the labels. See below

```
library(sjPlot)
library(titanic)
titanic_train$Sex_num<-ifelse(titanic_train$Sex=="male", 0, 1)
titanic_train$Embarked_test<-ifelse(titanic_train$Embarked=="C", "C", ifelse(titanic_train$Embarked=="Q", "Q", ifelse(titanic_train$Embarked=="S", "S", NA)))


fit1 <- glm(Survived ~ Embarked_test + Fare,family="binomial", data=titanic_train)
fit2 <- glm(Sex_num ~ Embarked_test + Fare,family="binomial", data=titanic_train)


model_obj<-plot_models(fit1, fit2)

model_obj + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Fare", "Embarked_testS", "Embarked_testQ") ) + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", limits = c(.001, 10000) ) + labs(color = "Outcomes")
```